# Rotten chicken smell

Tags: food-chemistry, cleaning

My boyfriend and I have a camper and he forgot to take a package of chicken out of the refrigerator before parking it. The chicken sat in the fridge which was off in the heat for a few months. We would like to pull the fridge out to dispose of it. However, many other systems run through the fridge. What chemicals will get rid of the awful smell or is it even possible? Thank you!

Comment: A good scrub with bleach is the first thing to try.

Comment: I would start more gently with soap and water and follow with wet baking soda. Many of the strongly smelling molecules produced by decay of flesh are amines, which are neutralized by the baking soda and made more water soluble.

Comment: If the entire inside of the refrigerator is stainless steel, you have a chance of killing the odor. But if there is any plastic in the interior, it will have absorbed that foul (no pun intended) smell and you will almost certainly know it every time you open the refrigerator door in the future. I hope I am wrong, but let us know what happens! Good luck! By the way, welcome and have an upvote!

Comment: BTW camping for a few months sounds like something only Mansour could do :p

Comment: Diluted vinegar is often used to wash fridges to get rid of smell.